# TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever I try to start up my web app, I get this Type error. Can't figure out why.

I started to get it after I updated some packages. I can't figure out which one was the problem or why the code that the error points to give wrong as it is code in my dependencies for Angular 8. I am not really sure what the error is even telling me.
I have tried to update all dependencies. I have looked at almost all the similar question solutions and they have not worked. I can't tell if it is a compiler error, typescript, or a dependency error.

**ERROR**

```
[error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (C:\Users\leahb\Desktop\NH\NH-Senior-Project\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:65:9)
    at C:\Users\leahb\Desktop\NH\NH-Senior-Project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:115:17

tslib.js at line 65
    (function (exporter) {
        var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };

        __extends = function (d, b) { 
            extendStatics(d, b); *//saying the error is coming from here*
            function __() { this.constructor = d; }
            d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
        };
```

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "nh",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "heroku"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.10.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  }
}
```

I expected the app to compile, build, and start up. Whenever I tried ng serve, ng test, or ng build I get this error.

Comment: All your angular libs should usually line up.  Try upgrading `@angular/cli` and `@angular/compiler` to version 8.  Also, anytime you upgrade the major version of Angular there is usually some work to do.  This site will give you the steps.  If you're going from 7 to 8 it is https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0

Comment: Please, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306898/typeerror-trying-to-run-npm-run-build/60213448#60213448

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem with my `angular@7` project after updating the CLI globally to version 8 and solve it by upgrading angular in my project to the latest version by running this command in my project directory:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

You can also use the `allow-dirty` flag to bypass the repo check:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

Also, there are other things to watch for when upgrading that has mentioned here: 
https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0

Answer (score 22):

I got the same error in my Angular app when running tests with `ng test`.

In my case, the cause of the issue was **circular dependencies**.

I had two classes that were part of some `index.ts`, but one of them imported the other one using the same index. This was causing a circular dependency because as a result of it the `index.ts` was imported multiple times.

Once removed the circular dependency, everything worked fine.

I was inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123468/3497671

Comment: just to add that this answer applies to React as well, i had a circular import which prevented a test from running

Comment: Had this error in a React App. Answer was circular dependencies in imports. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Using the flag `allow-dirty` allows you to bypass the repo check.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

Comment: yes it worked but why do u want to bypass.? Why don't we clean repository instead of bypassing?

Answer (score 4):

I had the issue and read Francesco Borzi answer and found out that the order of imports may have importance :

I use an index.ts
in the index.ts I import any local './*' Class then exports them at once
the order of imports was

```
import { Class2 } from './class2';
import { Class1 } from './class1';
```

and in Class2 I would have a

```
import Class1 from '.'

export Class2 extends Class1
```

It was trying to first compile Class2 and Class2 refers Class1. I inverted the imports in index.ts and it works now

Answer (score 1):

To Ionic users: In my case, the problem was the incompatibility between current angular/ionic cli's version and angular/ionic app's version.

Steps to solve:

1) Create a new project with ionic version 3, then compare the files packages.json.

```
ionic start Ionic3Project blank --type=ionic-angular
```

2) Inside Ionic3Project folder, build android

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

3) Open the packages.json of your main project and change the following versions of dependencies:

```
"@angular/*"
"@ionic-native/*"
"rxjs"
Also, replace the "scripts" part.
```

4) Delete your node_modules folder.

5) Delete your platform android folder (the entire platform folder or just android folder).

6) Run `npm install`

7) Add platform android

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

8) Build your app again

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

After follow these steps, I could build my app again.

Obs.: It's possible you got some issues related to plugins between these steps. In this case, you might need re-install the plugin(s). Do it and keep those steps in mind. Try to remove and re-add android after re-install the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue
fixed this way:

```
npm i @angular/compiler-cli@~8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Ionic App i downgraded the Angular CLI from 8.x.x to 5.2.11 using `npm i @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on Angular 9 so I will leave this answer here for folks looking for a fix on that version... I fixed it by removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling. This ensured that `ngcc` was forced to recompile the dependencies. Just ensure that your `postinstall`, NPM script looks like this:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc"
```