# Configuring production env

Tags: angular, npm, production-environment

I am trying to configure my app in its production environment by running

```
ng serve --configuration= production
```

but I am recieving the error *"An unhandled exception occurred: Project 'production' does not support the 'serve' target."* and I have no clue why or if this is a CLI issue. Here is the part in my angular.json:

hhkjhkjhlkjlkjlkjl;kjihiuhiuhoiugigguiouigiougiuhiuhphiohoihoihoihophpi

```
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
```

The full angular.json:

```
          {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "live-cicle": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/live-cicle",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/snazzy-info-window/dist/snazzy-info-window.css",
              "./node_modules/@mobiscroll/angular/dist/css/mobiscroll.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true,
              "ngswConfigPath": "src/ngsw-config.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "live-cicle:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "live-cicle:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "live-cicle:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.json"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "live-cicle-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "live-cicle:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "live-cicle:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "live-cicle"
}
```

Comment: Did you try **ng serve --prod=true**?

Comment: I get the error "‘true’ does not support the ‘serve’ target"

Comment: Which is your angular version?

Comment: Can you share full json file

Comment: Just updated to the latest: Angular CLI: 8.3.18
Node: 12.13.0

Comment: I changed the post to the full angular.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a needless space between `--configuration=` and `production`.

```
ng serve --configuration=production
```

or

```
ng serve --prod
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I get an error that 'An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined' while building

Comment: Can you describe complete stack trace please. I think it may be related to some code side error.

Comment: [error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (/Users/jonathanaugustin/Desktop/Websites/live-cicle/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:65:9)
    at /Users/jonathanaugustin/Desktop/Websites/live-cicle/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:115:17
    at /Users/jonathanaugustin/Desktop/Websites/live-cicle/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:314:6
...

Comment: Can you please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8. Seems like same issue here.