# An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

When I run `ng serve` in my terminal I get this error. I tried installing the latest CLI and compiler but it did not work.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular-file-explorer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.103",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "uuid": "3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.21"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0"
  }
}
```

This is my error log

```
[error] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:65:9)
    at E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:115:17
    at E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:314:6
    at E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:20:22
    at E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\OXP360\angular-file-explorer\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: maybe looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8)'s answers will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8)

Comment: Yeah I saw that thread and tried ng update @angular/cli @angular/core but still im getting the same error. Am I doing something wrong. I have attached the package.json file and error log for reference