# An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined (angular 8)

Tags: angular, typescript

Unable to execute(ng serve --open) the project due to error. Below is my **package.json**. Please help!!!!
The error started coming after upgrading angular to 8.

```
{
          "name": "mega-portal",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e"
          },
          "private": true,
          "dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/forms": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
            "@angular/router": "^8.2.2",
            "@epicor/kinetic": "^3.1.11",
            "@types/adal": "^1.0.29",
            "@types/underscore": "^1.9.2",
            "angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.1",
            "angular-highcharts": "^7.2.0",
            "angular-mailto": "^0.1.0",
            "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
            "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
            "core-js": "^2.5.4",
            "crypto": "^1.0.1",
            "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
            "fs": "0.0.1-security",
            "fusioncharts": "^3.13.4",
            "highcharts": "^7.1.1",
            "jstz": "^2.1.1",
            "net": "^1.0.2",
            "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
            "ngx-json-viewer-scrolling": "^2.3.1",
            "ngx-pagination": "^4.0.0",
            "os": "^0.1.1",
            "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
            "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
            "tls": "0.0.1",
            "underscore": "^1.9.1",
            "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
          },
          "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
            "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/forms": "^8.2.2",
            "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
            "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
            "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
            "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
            "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
            "karma": "^4.1.0",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
            "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
            "protractor": "~5.4.0",
            "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
            "tslint": "~5.11.0",
            "typescript": "3.5.3"
          },
          "browser": {
            "http": false,
            "https": false,
            "net": false,
            "path": false,
            "stream": false,
            "tls": false
          }
        }
```

Error I am getting -

> An unhandled exception occurred: Object prototype may only be an
>   Object or null: undefined (angular 8)

Appreciate any help!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8)

Comment: I tried those steps and it did not work.

Comment: Try doing a ```git clean -fdx && npm i``` and then run app.