# TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined in Ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am facing the following error when running `ionic cordova build android --prod` for my Ionic3 project. There is no error on just `ionic cordova build android`.

```
ionic-app-script task: "build" 
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined 
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (/Users/.../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:64:9)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:115:17
    at /Users/.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:314:6
    at /Users/.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

I have tried all the solutions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8) but it's not working.

Following are my ionic details.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.13 (/Users/meuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0
```

**EDIT:**

Details on `ng v`

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.23
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.23
@angular/cli                      8.3.23
@angular/compiler-cli             8.2.12
@angular/fire                     5.3.0
@schematics/angular               8.3.23
@schematics/update                0.803.23
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           3.12.0
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
}
```

Comment: The error seems to come from the Angular CLI. Which version do you have? Maybe installing the most recent one or going back one version fixes it.

Comment: I have added the version details for ng. Could you please take a look and help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Angular CLI. I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue. I changed `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.12"` to `"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11"` as per my angular versions and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node_modules folder.
 Delete your platform android folder (the entire platform folder or just android folder).

```
 Run npm install
```

Add platform android

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Build your app again

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Comment: I already tried it many times. Tried again. Still getting the same error.

Comment: plz try this https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/issues/866#issuecomment-326665729