# How do I resolve this `ionic serve` error?

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio, ionic-framework, python-3.7

I'm getting this error when trying to start my server using `ionic serve`. I've tried this both on windows 7 and windows 10 systems with different python versions, 3.7.0, 3.7.4, 3.8.0, all in a virtual environment and visual studio, and still nothing is working.

```
Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
[ng] TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
[ng]     at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
[ng]     at Object.__extends (C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:64:9)
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:115:17
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:314:6
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:3:17
[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:9:3)
[ng]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
[ng]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:20:22
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:10:17
[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:16:3)
[ng]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
[ng]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\index.js:23:23
[ng]     at C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\index.js:10:17
[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\00\Anaconda3\fullstack\coffee_shop\starter_code\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\index.js:16:3)
[ng]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
[ng]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8

Comment: please share you package.json