# angular 8 throw error `has no exported member 'ɵBrowserPlatformLocation'.`

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, single-spa

I am getting an error while i compile my angular as :

```
ERROR in node_modules/single-spa-angular/src/extra-providers.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"D:/trails/spa-angular-shared/login/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member 'ɵBrowserPlatformLocation'.

2 import { ɵBrowserPlatformLocation, LocationChangeEvent } from '@angular/common';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:single-spa:login": "ng build login --prod --deploy-url http://localhost:4203/",
    "serve:single-spa:login": "ng s --project login --disable-host-check --port 4203 --deploy-url http://localhost:4203/ --live-reload false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "single-spa": ">=5.4.0",
    "single-spa-angular": "^3.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: angular common doesn't have that class, it have PlatformLocation not ɵbrowserplatformlocation

Comment: which version of single-spa-angular you are using?

Comment: @AakashGarg - i am using `  "single-spa-angular": "^3.1.0",`

Comment: this might help :- https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/232

Comment: https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/232#issuecomment-658584295

Comment: I am updated to `    "single-spa": "5.3.1",    "single-spa-angular": "^4.5.0",`  But still getting the same error

Comment: check this link and follow these steps :- https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/232#issuecomment-658584295

Comment: I updated with recommaned version of `single-spa` and `single-spa-angular` after getting this error `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'single-spa-angular/lib/webpack'`

Comment: I removed the `node_modules` and reinstalled all. but getting same error

Comment: it seems some compatibility issue with single-spa, single-spa-angular and @angular/custom-webpack.

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with single-spa-angular schematics which was fixed in v 3.5.3. It installs latest version even if you specify a version before if was fixed in v3.5.3.

https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/releases/tag/v3.5.3

Follow following steps

1. Delete node_modules.
2. Delete package-lock.json.
3. remove single-spa-angular and single-spa from package.json.
4. running ng add single-spa-angular@3.5.3
5. Run npm install.
6. Run your application.

For more information you can also read here :-

https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/issues/208
https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/pull/231

Comment: Yes, to worked. But while I import I am getting the error as :` Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at extendStatics (tslib.es6.js:21)
    at __extends (tslib.es6.js:25)
    at extra-providers.ts:14
    at Object.<anonymous> (extra-providers.ts:14)
    at Object.execute (amd.js:56)
    at Object.declaration.execute (named-exports.js:42)
    at doExec (system.js:478)
    at postOrderExec (system.js:474)
    at system.js:457`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421582/typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined-angular-8

Answer (score 0):

If anyone getting this same error with Angular 15+ . Then pls update your single-spa and single-spa-angular lib version.

```
"single-spa": "^6.0.0",
"single-spa-angular": "^9.0.1",
```

It will solve your problem.